# How do I put Netbook Edition on my new Acer Aspire One D255?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, acer, aspire-one

I'm going on a 9 month Round The World trip and I have just bought an Acer Netbook to keep me company. I'll be mainly using it to update my blog, keep in touch with family and friends, upload photos, update my iphone etc.

It has come with Windows 7 Starter pre-loaded, which is fine, and I have the option to dual boot into Android if I want, but I would rather use Ubuntu Netbook Edition, as I have been using Ubuntu on my laptop for about the last 5 years.

However from looking on the Ubuntu website it isn't clear how I can do this.

Can anyone explain, in a step by step, easy to understand and uncomplicated way (for a non-geek) how I can download and install Netbook Edition please?

I'd be really grateful.

Huge thanks in advance,

Kat x x

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK ubuntu has merged netbook-edition to desktop as unity has become the default desktop.

You need to:

[Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) an iso of ubuntu desktop.

Burn it on a CD or use something like [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a live-usb.

Reboot and boot to your live-cd or USB and check out ubuntu and install it.

Most of the steps are well described in the above link that I have atatched. Just see the "Show Me How" section.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 

I have followed the instructions on the Ubuntu website and I have downloaded 11.04.

I have tried about 4 blank USB sticks through System > Administration > Start Up Disc Creator and every time I try to Make a Startup disc it says 'Installation failed'. Do you know what I might be doing wrong or why this might be?

Quite frustrating, as I'm really keen to get 11.04 on my netbook and I'm starting to run out of time before my trip . . .

Thanks,

Kat

Answer (score 0):

download the 11.04 image from here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

If your netbook came with windows and you wish to multiboot you could do the following :

Use winrar to open the image file, then extract the wubi file into the directory where your image file is located. Close winrar and execute the wubi.exe file. select the size of your ubuntu installation as large as you can afford(30gb is the max for this form of install), and enter a username and password in the correct fields. Click install and once it is done extracting the image it will say reboot to continue... reboot and follow installation prompts. See the image :

http://technofriends.files.wordpress.com/2008/08/wubi-123_small.png

the wubi interface hasn't changed yet, so it will look the same except it will say 11.04 and the only things you will select here is the installation size and your passwords and username if you wish to change it...
Once you have completed the install, you will be posed with a grub menu at startup where you can select ubuntu or windows, but the default will be windows, so you will manually have to select ubuntu every time if you wish to use it.

http://cache5.groovypost.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/image215.png

enjoy your travels!

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 

I have followed the instructions on the Ubuntu website and I have downloaded 11.04.

I have tried about 4 blank USB sticks through System > Administration > Start Up Disc Creator and every time I try to Make a Startup disc it says 'Installation failed'. Do you know what I might be doing wrong or why this might be?

Quite frustrating, as I'm really keen to get 11.04 on my netbook and I'm starting to run out of time before my trip . . .

Thanks,

Kat